# Background extraction based on OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I trying to make a programm based on openCV, that extracts the Background in Video, my Problem is that that the Program take a small change in the intensity (light) as change of the whole background, here is my code I wrote it based on OpenCV samples,

```
   #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
   #include <opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
   #include <iostream>


int main(int argc, const char** argv){
 cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg_model;
bg_model.history = 10000;
bg_model.bShadowDetection = false;
cv::Mat img, fgmask,fgimg,smooth;
bool update =true;
int key =0;

while(key !=27){
    cap >> img;
    cv::blur(img,smooth,cv::Size(20,10));
    //update the model 
    if(fgimg.empty())
        fgimg.create(img.size(),img.type());
    bg_model(smooth,fgmask,update ? -1 :0);
    fgimg = cv::Scalar::all(0);
    img.copyTo(fgimg,fgmask);


    cv::imshow("fgimg",fgimg);
    cv::imshow("fgmask",fgmask);
    cv::imshow("img",img);
    std::cout << bg_model.backgroundRatio << std::endl;
    if(key == 'x')
        update= !update;
    if( update){
            std::cout <<  "update on " <<std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "update off "<<std::endl;
        }
    key = 0;
    key = cv::waitKey(10);
}
 }
```

has anyone an idea how to downgrade  the sensivity of the program to the intensity.

thanks in advance for any help !!

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the sensitivity by changing `nmixtures` and `minArea` values of `bg_model` using the method `initialize`

as in the link: http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_background_subtractor_m_o_g2.html

Comment: Is there documentation the explains, what those parameters are actually doing, I've on openCV website, and they don't explain it that well, thanks for your help

Comment: @Engine, i don't know but nmixtures/minArea  is important in sensitivity. You can increase  minArea   to decrease it